# When I ask a simple question should I ask it in negative form?

Tags: negation, questions

My textbook is prompting me to ask questions:

> "Don't you want to see a movie?"
> eiga o mimasen ka?
>
> "Don't you want to eat dinner?"
> bangohan o tabemasen ka?

I'm wondering if I should be asking these types of negative questions instead something like this:

> "Do you want to see a movie?"
> eiga o mimas ka?

etc...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Questions can be asked in either positive or negative. They only vary by politeness (with the latter being more so).

> 映画{えいが}を見{み}ませんか。
>   映画を見ますか。

These are two nearly identical ways of asking the same thing (Do you want to see a movie?). The only difference is that the former is slightly more polite.

Also, unlike English, responses are reversed when the question is in the negative. What I mean by that is:

> 映画{えいが}を見{み}ますか。 (Do you want to see a movie?)
>   はい (=Yes, I **do** want to see a movie)
>   いいえ (=No, I **don't** want to see a movie)

However:

> 映画{えいが}を見{み}ませんか。(Don't you want to see a movie?)
>   はい (=No, I **don't** want to see a movie)
>   いいえ (=Yes, I **do** want to see a movie)

Comment: Do Japanese people sometimes get confused about these yes/no? In Russian and English I often hear stuff like _are you saying "no" to my "no" or just "no"?_.

Answer (score 3):

These "negative questions" as you refer to them are an appropriate way to invite someone to do something with you.

So

> 映画｛えいが｝を見｛み｝ませんか。

can read as

> 1. Won't you see a movie (with me)?
> 2. Would you like to see a movie (with me)?

Your example

> 映画を見ますか。

can read as

> 1. Are you going to see a/the movie?
> 2. Will you watch the movie?

For illustrative purposes, "negative questions" can also be interpreted as a genuine question.

> 山田｛やまだ｝さんは英語｛えいご｝を話｛はな｝しませんか。

This can read as

> Doesn't Yamada-san speak English?